# Quantifying error in the reconstruction of convex polytopes from moments

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, st.statistics, convex-geometry, convex-polytopes, geometric-probability

The problem of reconstructing a geometric object from its moments is of interest in a variety of fields. In the paper *[The Inverse Moment Problem for Convex Polytopes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.5723.pdf)*, the authors show that a convex polytope $P$ with $m$ vertices can be uniquely determined by its moments up to order $2m - 1$.

My question is: how can we, knowing say $(2m - 1) - n$ moments, quantify how "far away" members of the resultant space of potential reconstructions are from the true one?

Any suggestions or pointers to existing results would be much appreciated!